# Check if data is already in list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am working on a linked list project and I have two functions that I can't get to work right.

First I have a insert function that adds an element to the list. But the function first wants to check if the element is already in the list. It should do that by using the bool function contain(). That should return true if the element is already in the list

**my insert function:**

```
void StringSet::insert(string element)
{
    NodePtr temp =head;
    if (contains("element") == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new StringNode;
        head->setData(element);
        head->setLink(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        temp = new StringNode;
        temp->setData(element);
        temp->setLink(head);
        head = temp;
    }

}
```

**And my contain function:**

```
bool StringSet::contains(string element)
{
      NodePtr temp = head;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->getData() == element)
        {
            cout<<"This country has already been registered!"<<endl;
            return true;
        }

        temp = temp->getLink();
    }


}
```

Comment: How is `getLink()` defined? `contains` looks ok (except that it's missing `return false`.

Comment: `contains("element")` is vastly different from `contains(element)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a literal rather then a variable in your method call:

```
if (contains("element") == true)
```

Should be:

```
if (contains(element) == true)
```

Comment: Ahh Unbelievable. Spent 30 mins staring at it and probably changed everything else :).
But it works now, Thank you! :)

Comment: @user3265963 It can happen to the best of programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Function contains has undefined behaviour because it returns nothing in case when there is no target element in the list. Change it the following way

```
bool StringSet::contains( const string &element ) const
{
    NodePtr temp = head;

    while( temp != NULL && temp->getData() != element ) temp = temp->getLink();

    return ( temp != NULL );
}
```

And change its call from

```
if (contains("element") == true)
```

to

```
if ( contains( element) )
```

because "element" is not the same as element.